# How to pass command line arguments to NodeJS launched from an executable script

Tags: node.js, npm

How to set what would otherwise be command-line arguments to `node` for a NodeJS process run from a launcher script? (The sh/CMD scripts `npm` places into `node_modules/.bin`.)

Plenty of NodeJS libraries / frameworks come with their own runner script, e.g. [`zeit/micro`](https://github.com/zeit/micro) or [`moleculer`](https://moleculer.services/0.12/docs/runner.html) that's usually executed from a `npm` script. This presents a problem in development, since in my case I want to do the equivalent of:

```
node --inspect -r ts-node/register -r dotenv-safe/config src/index.ts
```

(Except, of course, that does nothing since index.ts just exports something for the runner to pick up.)

Is there some "clean", preferably generic (i.e. not specific to a given framework's runner exposing those command line params) way that I'm missing to do this, ideally one that works as a npm script? The only thing that seems like it would work would be for e.g. `micro`:

```
node-dev -r ts-node/register ./node_modules/micro-dev/bin/micro-dev.js ./src/index.ts
```

which is kind of a mouthful from the Redundant Department of Redundancy Department and seems to obviate the point of having those launcher scripts. (It also won't work if the runner spawns other Node processes, but that's not a problem I'm actually having.) I'd like to not have to duplicate what the launcher scripts are already doing. I'm also aware of `npx` having `--node-arg` but npx is a whole another can of worms. (On Windows it's five seconds of startup time and one spurious error message just to run a script I already have installed; it also won't find an already installed package if it can't find its `.cmd` launcher script, e.g. when using Docker to run the dev environment. In short I'd rather not use npx for this.)

---

To clear up the confusion that seems to crop up in the comments: I want to override the command line parameters that affect the behaviour of *the NodeJS runtime itself* executing the runner script, not pass parameters to the script itself or to my code. That is, the options listed here: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but effectively you want to override the command line params being passed by a `child_process.exec` or `child_process.spawn` call within a script you are calling?

Comment: @Catalyst No, the command line params *to the NodeJS runtime* that script is being spawned with.

Comment: so just checking that I get it - an example would be to be able to do `node -r overwrite-da-stuff.js sample.js` and have sample.js be invoked with some custom node.js command line params specified within `overwrite-da-stuff.js`? If that is the case it would be similar to being able to turn on `--inspect` from within application code? If so, I doubt you can beat child process... otherwise it is going to be only allowed for specific flags which do not pose security risks.

Comment: @Catalyst - I think you're close, but not really aware of what `-r` does? It makes the node runtime `require()` a module before it runs the script you specify. In my example, `ts-node/register` is a module that when required, registers ts-node as a script loader, making it possible to load TypeScript files directly, compiling them on the fly, without having to do so yourself up-front. Similar is `dotenv`, which loads a `.env` file in the current folder and adds its contents to `process.env`.

Comment: What I want is to not have to duplicate what NPM's launcher scripts do, and spawning a node process myself whether through the command line or from a script is kind of that

Comment: I get it now, I did check what -r does before saying what I said, I just wasn't sure how it was playing into what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to write a little wrapper script that uses the current process execPath to run child_process.execFile.

So the sample here is to be able to do

`node --expose-http2 --zero-fill-buffers -r ./some-module.js ./test.js`

but not actually write that out, instead have wrap.js inject the args:

`node ./wrap.js ./test.js`

I tested running this via npm in a package.json, and it works fine. I tested that it was working by having `some-module.js` stick a value on the global object, and then logging it in `test.js`.

Files involved:

`wrap.js`

```
const child_process = require('child_process');

const nodeArgs = ['--expose-http2', '--zero-fill-buffers', '-r', './some-module.js'];
const runTarget = process.argv[2];

console.log('going to wrap', runTarget, 'with', nodeArgs);

const finalArgs = nodeArgs.concat(runTarget).concat(process.argv.slice(2));

const child = child_process.execFile(
  process.execPath,
  finalArgs,
  {
    env: process.env,
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    stdio: 'inherit'
  }, (e, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log('process completed');
    if (e) {
      process.emit('uncaughtException', e);
    }
  });

child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

and

`some-module.js`

```
global.testval = 2;
```

and

`test.js`

```
console.log('hi guys, did the wrap work?', global.testval)
```

EDIT: So upon further thought, this solution really only satisfies wrapping the initial runner. But most tools, such as mocha re-spawn a sub process which would then lose this effect. To really get the job done, you can proxy each of the child process calls and somewhat enforce that calls to `spawn` and such also include your args.

I rewrote the code to reflect this. Here's a new setup:

`package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node -r ./ensure-wrapped.js node_modules/mocha/$(npm view mocha bin.mocha) ./test.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mocha": "^5.1.0"
  }
}
```

`ensure-wrapped.js`

```
const child_process = require('child_process');

// up here we can require code or do whatever we want;

global.testvalue = 'hi there'
const customParams = ['--zero-fill-buffers'];

// the code below injects itself into any child process's spawn/fork/exec calls
// so that it propogates

const matchNodeRe = /((:?\s|^|\/)node(:?(:?\.exe)|(:?\.js)|(:?\s+)|$))/;
const ensureWrappedLocation = __filename;

const injectArgsAndAddToParamsIfPathMatchesNode = (cmd, args, params) => {
  params.unshift(...customParams);
  params.unshift(args);
  if (!Array.isArray(args)) { // all child_proc functions do [] optionally, then other params
    args = []
    params.unshift(args);
  }

  if (!matchNodeRe.test(cmd)) {
    return params;
  }

  args.unshift(ensureWrappedLocation);
  args.unshift('-r');

  return params;
}

child_process._exec = child_process.exec;
child_process.exec = (cmd, ...params) => {
  // replace node.js node.exe or /path/to/node to inject -r ensure-wrapped.js ...args..
  // leaves alone exec if it isn't calling node
  cmd = cmd.replace(matchNodeRe, '$1 -r ' + ensureWrappedLocation + ' ');
  return child_process._exec(cmd, ...params)
}
child_process._execFile = child_process.execFile;
child_process.execFile = (path, args, ...params) => {
  params = injectArgsAndAddToParamsIfPathMatchesNode(path, args, params);
  return child_process._execFile(path, ...params)
}
child_process._execFileSync = child_process.execFileSync;
child_process.execFileSync = (path, args, ...params) => {
  params = injectArgsAndAddToParamsIfPathMatchesNode(path, args, params);
  return child_process._execFileSync(path, ...params);
}
child_process._execSync = child_process.execSync;
child_process.execSync = (cmd, ...params) => {
  cmd = cmd.replace(matchNodeRe, '$1 -r ' + ensureWrappedLocation + ' ');
  return child_process._exec(bin, ...args)
}
child_process._fork = child_process.fork;
child_process.fork = (module, args, ...params) => {
  params = injectArgsAndAddToParamsIfPathMatchesNode(process.execPath, args, params);
  return child_process._fork(module, ...params);
}
child_process._spawn = child_process.spawn;
child_process.spawn = (cmd, args, ...params) => {
  params = injectArgsAndAddToParamsIfPathMatchesNode(cmd, args, params);
  return child_process._spawn(cmd, ...params)
}
child_process._spawnSync = child_process.spawnSync;
child_process.spawnSync = (cmd, args, ...params) => {
  params = injectArgsAndAddToParamsIfPathMatchesNode(cmd, args, params);
  return child_process._spawnSync(cmd, ...params);
}
```

`test.js`

```
describe('test', () => {
  it('should have the global value pulled in by some-module.js', (done) => {
    if (global.testvalue !== 'hi there') {
      done(new Error('test value was not globally set'))
    }
    return done();
  })
})
```

Please never put code like this into a node module that's published. modifying the global library functions is pretty bad.

Comment: This is actually pretty close if NPM has some sort of API to find out the path to the entrypoint of a package for the script to run, I’ll poke at it later

Comment: @millimoose added a more robust sample that should support most runners

Answer (score 1):

Everything passed in the command line AFTER your nodejs application is parsed into an array called process.argv.  So...

```
node myapp.js foo bar hello 5000
```

In your nodejs code...

```
const args = process.argv;
console.log(args[0]);
console.log(args[1]);
console.log(args[2]);
console.log(args[3]);
```

would yield...

```
foo
bar
hello
5000
```

Comment: This is not what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to affect the options of the NodeJS runtime itself, not my code that will ultimately get executed. I want to change [these options](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html) when I'm not actually using the `node` executable directly.

Answer (score 1):

I didnt get clear scenario of your problem,but as your question title ,we can execute the any cmd command from nodejs using npm libraries like:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'
import cmd from 'node-cmd'

const getAsync = Promise.promisify(cmd.get, { multiArgs: true, context: cmd })

getAsync('node -v').then(data => {
  console.log('cmd data', data)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('cmd err', err)
})
```

Comment: Not quite. What you described is what the runner scripts I mention might be doing, but I'm not the one doing it. My own code is just a function exported to some framework that handles the plumbing.